# ELM Models: How Can I Transfer A Value Into A List Of Values?

Tags: elm

I want to add a certain value to a list. Both are inside my ELM-model:

```
type alias Model =
{   syllables : List Syllable
,   words : List Word
,   newSyllable : String
,   newWord : String
}
```

I want to add the **newSyllable** `value` to the `list` of **syllables**, when I click the button.

I placed this attribute inside my view:

```
onClick TransferSyllable
```

Everything works right, but I wonder how I can transfer one value of my model into the list of values!?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is my definition of "**Syllable**":

```
type alias Syllable =
{   content : String
,   start : Bool
,   mid : Bool
,   end : Bool
}
```

I want to insert the value to the end of the list.

Comment: What is your definition of `Syllable`? And are you trying to put the new value at the beginning, end, or somewhere in the middle if the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Syllable` is a record type with four fields, and `newSyllable` is just a string, you'll need a function that turns a `String` into a `Syllable`. I'll assume that function has the signature:

```elm
makeSyllable : String -> Syllable
```

Adding the syllable onto the end of the list can be done using [`List.append`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List#append). Since `append` takes a `List a`, you'll need to add brackets around `newSyllable` when passing it to `append`:

```elm
{ model | syllables = List.append model.syllables [ makeSyllable model.newSyllable ] }
```

Comment: I thank you so much, i was thinking in this direction, but you gave me the last hint !